# Toggle alert visibility using highcharts

Tags: highcharts, alert

I am using highcharts to generate the line chart after loading huge data. Since the data is huge it is taking extra time to load the data and show the chart. Is it possible to show an alert (like: data loading) before start loading data and hide that alert/message after showing the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [loading](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#loading) options in the API.  Since the chart has to exist before you and use the options, I find it best to use in the following workflow:

- Create a "blank" graph before loading data with a `redraw` event to hide the loading message and the `load` event set to show the loading message:

  ```
  // blank graph
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
          events: {
              redraw: function(){
                  this.hideLoading();
              },
              load: function(){
                  this.showLoading();
              }
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Make your AJAX call to retrieve data and load into chart using `addSeries()`, the above events will show/hide the message.

Here's an [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/998Ft/).